# Regarding setting of cookies in java

Tags: java, cookies

**Scenerio :** Lets say we are moving from one application to another using a link, but the destination application using cookie to get the required values.

So am trying to set the values into the cookie in the parent application like
response.addCookie(new Cookie("Parameter", Parameter));

So when i land the child application, am not able to get the values of the cookie that is set

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Unless the destination is the same server, that won't work.

Comment: For this case, i sent the value through the request to another application and try to set into the cookie in the child application. Even in this case the cookie is not accessible in the same application

Comment: You are looking for [CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html).